# How do get php array in javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php

I am using following code .

```
<?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = '****';
    $dbpass = '******';

    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

    if(! $conn ) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM mytable';
    mysql_select_db('sujeet_db');
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

    if(! $retval ) {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
    }

     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
      echo "EMP ID :{$row['firstname']}  <br> ".
         "EMP NAME : {$row['lastname']} <br> ".
         "EMP SALARY : {$row['doj']} <br> ".

         "--------------------------------<br>";

     }

     echo "Fetched data successfully\n";

     mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

to get data from db . But I want to store these data in JavaScript variable for future use. Like `var users=$row;`  but it is not working.

Comment: You need to put javascript code inside script tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do this by assigning inside script tag here is how.

```
 <script>
   var spge = '<?php echo json_encode($row); ?>';
   alert(spge);
  console.log(spge);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by putting your mysql result in json format and print it with script tag to use it in javascript like:

```
<script>
   var result = '<?php echo json_encode($row);?>';
</script>
```